# Paraphrasing "Peter was abandoned by his parents at an early age and took to stealing." to participles

Tags: past-participles, participles, present-participles

From my homework about participles, I have to paraphrase this to participles but I don't know how to.

> Peter was abandoned by his parents at an early age and took to stealing.

Comment: What do you want to know? If you didn't already know, in your example sentence, "abandoned" is a ***Past** Participle*, but "stealing" is probably more properly referred to as a ***gerund***, rather than a ***Present** Participle* (because it's being used as a ***noun*** - compare *He took to **drink / drinking***, noting that *He took to steal* isn't valid).

Comment: Is this what you want? *"Peter, abandoned by his parents at an early age, took to stealing."*